# N-grams computational overhead

Tags: python, nlp

There are various algorithms for computing N-grams. I'm interested in [this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_lda.html) specific claim on the `Phrases` module (in Python `Gensim`):

> **Important**: Computing n-grams of large dataset can be very computationally and memory intensive.

Specifically, if I have a corpus of N words in total length (N_0 unique words, if that is what matters), what exactly is the overhead of computing bigrams/trigrams using `Phrases`?